# How to make a customize role and view a specific plugins base on that role?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, menus, user-roles, plugin-recommendation

is there anyone can suggested or give me an idea.
i created a customize WordPress plugin. it was called "**Spark 3cx client**"

First when i login using "admin" account. I can view or access the admin dashboard.
[image]
Then what i wanted is to access the same page of admin to get the same GUI but only the specific plugin will appear on sidebar, using the customize role/user credential when logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a custom admin page with `add_menu_page` function.

The function has a argument `$capability` which you can set the which users will be able to view and access the page

`add_menu_page`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

`Roles and capabilities`

https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/